# Text does not adapt to TextView

Tags: android, textview, android-textview-autosize

I need to insert a large text in a `TextView`, but when pasting the text it does not adapt to the size of the `TextView`, because it has exceeded the width of the `TextView` and the text is giant, how to fix this?

Note: I need to correct it using the Android Studio visual interface.

[image: My PrintScreen]

Comment: Hi, please add the layout file

Comment: Please state the behavior you need to implement or add design for it

Comment: Check this out : https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/autosizing-textview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To set optimal size of the text in TextView You can use `autoSizeTextType` property. To do it Your TextView must have fixed sizes or `match_parent`. Then You can use `autoSizeTextType` It looks something like this:

```xml
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:text="@string/lorem_ipsum"
    app:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
    app:autoSizeMinTextSize="12sp"
    app:autoSizeMaxTextSize="100sp"
    />
```

Results:

TextView height : `150dp`

[image]

---

TextView height : `300dp`

[image]

[Here is a short video on YouTube with great explanation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JYrpEAz_A1U&ab_channel=AndroidDevelopers)

Comment: Thank You so much.